# Iterating through the union of several Java Map key sets efficiently

Tags: java, dictionary, key, set, union

In one of my Java 6 projects I have an array of [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instances as input to a method which has to iterate through all keys (i.e. through the union of the key sets of all maps) and work with the associated values. Not all keys exist in all maps and the method should not go through each key more than once or alter the input maps.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
Set<Object> keyset = new HashSet<Object>();

for (Map<Object, Object> map : input) {
    for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
        if (keyset.add(key)) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The [HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instance ensures that no key will be acted upon more than once.

Unfortunately this part of the code is rather critical performance-wise, as it is called *very* frequently. In fact, according to the profiler over 10% of the CPU time is spent in the [`HashSet.add()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29) method.

I am trying to optimise this code us much as possible. The use of [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) with its more efficient iterators (in comparison to the plain [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) was a significant boost, but I was hoping to reduce what is essentially book-keeping time to the minimum.

Putting all the keys in the HashSet before-hand, by using [`addAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) proved to be less efficient, due to the cost of calling [`HashSet.contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) afterwards.
At the moment I am looking at whether I can use a bitmap (well, a `boolean[]` to be exact) to avoid the HashSet completely, but it may not be possible at all, depending on my key range.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Preferrably something that will not pose restrictions on the keys?

EDIT:

A few clarifications and comments:

- I do need *all* the values from the maps - I cannot drop any of them.
- I also need to know which map each value came from. The missing part (`...`) in my code would be something like this:

  ```
  for (Map<Object, Object> m : input) {
      Object v = m.get(key);

      // Do something with v
  }
  ```

  A simple example to get an idea of what I need to do with the maps would be to print all maps in parallel like this:

  ```
  Key Map0 Map1 Map2
  F   1    null 2
  B   2    3    null
  C   null null 5
  ...
  ```

  That's not what I am actually doing, but you should get the idea.
- The input maps are *extremely* variable. In fact, each call of this method uses a different set of them. Therefore I would not gain anything by caching the union of their keys.
- My keys are all String instances. They are sort-of-interned on the heap using a separate HashMap, since they are pretty repetitive, therefore their hash code is already cached and most hash validations (when the HashMap implementation is checking whether two keys are actually equal, after their hash codes match) boil down to an identity comparison (`==`). The profiler confirms that only 0.5% of the CPU time is spent on [`String.equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`String.hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29).

EDIT 2:

Based on the suggestions in the answers, I made a few tests, profiling and benchmarking along the way. I ended up with roughly a 7% increase in performance. What I did:

- I set the initial capacity of the HashSet to double the collective size of all input maps. This gained me something in the region of 1-2%, by eliminating most (all?) `resize()` calls in the HashSet.
- I used `Map.entrySet()` for the map I am currently iterating. I had originally avoided this approach due to the additional code and the fear that the extra checks and `Map.Entry` getter method calls would outweigh any advantages. It turned out that the overall code was slightly faster.
- I am sure that some people will start screaming at me, but here it is: Raw types. More specifically I used the raw form of HashSet in the code above. Since I was already using `Object` as its content type, I do not lose any type safety. The cost of that useless `checkcast` operation when calling `HashSet.add()` was apparently important enough to produce a 4% increase in performance when removed. Why the JVM insists on checking casts to `Object` is beyond me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't provide a replacement for your approach but a few suggestions to (slightly) optimize the existing code.

1. Consider initializing the hash set with a capacity (the sum of the sizes of all maps). This avoids/reduces resizing of the set during an add operation
2. Consider not using the `keySet()` as it will always create a new set in the background. Use the `entrySet()`, that should be much faster
3. Have a look at the implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` - if they are "expensive", then you have a negative impact on the `add` method.

Comment: In reverse order: 3) See my edit, `equals()` and `hashCode()` are not a problem.

Comment: 2a) Both `keySet()` and `entrySet()` create a Set object, once for each map - it's cached afterwards. The only reason `entrySet()` is thought faster is because you avoid a `get()` for the value afterwards.

Comment: 2b) Since I am accessing multiple maps "in parallel", that would only work for the map currently in iteration. I'll consider it, but I'm afraid that the cost of the resulting juggling ("if this is the map I have a value from, use it, otherwise get it") and the Map.Entry getter method calls may outweigh the cost of a single get, despite the JVM inlining and optimisations. The code will certainly get uglier. I'll benchmark/profile and see...

Comment: 3) I had originally used a HashSet with an initial capacity set to the average size of the keyset union, increased to the nearest power of 2. Unfortunately the cost of initializing a larger hash table and of that particular HashSet constructor actually had a negative impact. I now revisited the idea, by using the sum of the map sizes and calling the `HashSet(int)` constructor only when the size is over 16. This did have a small, but measurable, increase in performance. I'll play around with the capacity and the load factor and see where it'll take me. +1

Answer (score 1):

How you avoid using a HashSet depends on what you are doing.

I would only calculate the union once each time the `input` is changed.  This should be relatively rare conmpared with the number of lookups.

```
// on an update.
Map<Key, Value> union = new LinkedHashMap<Key, Value>();
for (Map<Key, Value> map : input) 
    union.putAll(map);


// on a lookup.
Value value = union.get(key);
// process each key once
for(Entry<Key, Value> entry: union) {
   // do something.
}
```

Comment: See my edit, I should have probably been more clear. Bottomline: I cannot drop any of they values, as your approach does. And the input maps change with each method call, so I cannot cache the union of their keys :-/

Comment: Could you use an Enum for the keyset?  That would be much more efficient.

Comment: Uh, definitely not. The keys are read from a database. The only reason I can sort-of-intern them is because I know that they are in the range of a few thousands, as opposed to millions, or more...

Comment: So if you are reading the data from a database each time doesn't that take alot longer than what you are doing in Java?

Comment: No, I am doing *a lot* of heavy-duty processing. The DB driver takes about 15% wall-clock time and I am already working on it...

Comment: So instead of building your List of Map, can you go from the database to this loop directly.

Comment: The maps are in fact BSON objects, as created by the MongoDB Java driver. I cannot really avoid their creation and I am not sure I should, since a Map *is* the natural represenation of JSON/BSON objects in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Option A is to use the .values() method and iterate through it. But I suppose you already had thought of it.

If the code is called so often, then it might be worth creating additional structures (depending of how often the data is changed). Create a new HashMap; every key in any of your hashmaps is a key in this one and the list keeps the HashMaps where that key appears.

This will help if the data is somewhat static (related to the frequency of queries), so the overload from managing the structure is relatively small, and if the key space is not very dense (keys do not repeat themselves a lot in different HashMaps), as it will save a lot of unneeded contains().

Of course, if you are mixing data structures it is better if you encapsulate all in your own data structure.

Comment: See my edit. Unfortunately, the input maps are not static - far from it. Maintaining such a structure is definitely out of the question...

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Guava's Sets.union() http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#union(java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set)